Issues migrating Wicket 1.4 to wicket 9
In wicket 1.4.x I have custom Container + panel for my pages:
example:
MyPage.java
public class MyPage extends WebPage {
     public MyPage(){
         add(new CustContainer, "custContainer");
     }

}

MyPage.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head></head>
<body>
     <div wicket:id="custContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>

Custcontainer.java
public class CustContainer extends WebMarkupContainer {
     private Component comp;
     public CustContainer(String id){
          super(id);
          this.comp = new CustPanel("custPanel");
     }

     @Override
     protected void onRender(MarkupStream markupStream) {
          comp.render(getMarkupStream());
     }
}

CustPanel.java
public class CustPanel extends Panel {
     public CustPanel(String id){
          super(id);
          add(new Label("label1","This is my Label"));
     }
}

CustPanel.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<wicket:panel>
     <div><span wicket:id="label1"></span></div>
</wicket:panel>
</html>

In wicket 1.4.x this code (which is simplified)  works very well, but in wicket 9 Component.render() method have removed MarkupStream as param. And when I'm trying to just Component.render() it does not understand anymore that it needs to take custPanel.html <div><span wicket:id="label1"></span></div> part and insert into MyPage.html markup inside <div wicket:id="custContainer"> HERE </div>
Question: anyone have idea how to solve this issue ? because adding <div wicket:id="custPanel"></div> into
custContainer div block is not a option because I need to add these panels/component id's dynamically from db:
example:
<div wicket:id="custContainer"> <div wicket:id="custPanel"></div> </div>

So I somehow need to add <div wicket:id="custPanel"> into custContainer div block before rendering markup.
BTW:
@Override
public void onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag openTag)

is not a solution, its only changes markup after markup render and exception is thrown.
Long story short: I want all CustPanel.html wicket body included into MyPage.html div block with wiket id = custContainer
<div wicket:id="custContainer">HERE I need CustPanel.html wicket content to be rendered/included</div>


since Wicket 1.5 you can set component markup explicitly with Componet.setMarkup or use interface IMarkupResourceStreamProvider to generate it.

yes but i do not need to generate, i need to read it from Markup files -> MyPage.html and CustPanel.html
Componet.setMarkup() sets markup but still at that point it does not want to read/load existing markup file.
Can you please provide with some short example how to use IMarkupResourceStreamProvider  ?

You can find an example for IMarkupResourceStreamProvider in the user guide: https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/10.x/single.html#_generating_html_markup_from_code . See if it can fit your needs.
